# $(window).load not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(window).load` not working properly in IE but working properly in Chrome.

`$(document).ready(function()` wont  solve my problem.
I want to call my function once whole page load completes.
Can anybody come across same situation.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".testdiv #Value").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/:/g," > "));
    });
})
```

```html
<div id="Value">
      <input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="1" data-displayvalue="tes1" value="1">
      <label for="test1">test1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="Value">
      <input type="checkbox" id="test2" name="2" data-displayvalue="test2" value="2">
      <label for="test2">test2</label>
    </div>
    <div id="Value">
      <input type="checkbox" id="test3" name="3" data-displayvalue="test3" value="3">
      <label for="test3">test3</label>
    </div>
    <div id="Value">
      <input type="checkbox" id="test4" name="4" data-displayvalue="test4" value="4">
      <label for="test4">test4:yuv</label>
    </div>
    <div id="Value">
      <input type="checkbox" id="test5" name="5" data-displayvalue="test5" value="5">
      <label for="test5">test5:xyz</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why isnt it working? What version of jquery?

Comment: @KevinB jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: then your code should work as-is. you aren't giving enough information to recreate the problem.

Comment: @KevinB i have added

Comment: you can't have duplicate id's...

Comment: @KevinB in sharepoint display template it is  coming..i cant do much in that

Comment: Then you can't use the `Value` id for anythinig useful. use another selector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130578/discussion-between-pawan-kotak-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score -1):

I have used this successfully in the past to wait for EVERYTHING to fully load:

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    //after everything has loaded
});
```

Comment: `.bind` has been deprecated in jQuery 3.0, use `.on` instead

https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/